# Inequality of quantile function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I tried to prove the following inequality but got stuck:

Let $x \in \mathbb R$ and $p \in [0,1]$ and $X$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$. Let $A_p := \{z \in \mathbb R; F_X(z) \le p\}$. Define $F_X^{-1+}(p) := \sup A_p$. Then, I want to prove that
$P[X < x] \le p \Longleftrightarrow x \le F_X^{-1+}(p)$.

Ideas: 
$\Rightarrow$: I want to show that $x \in A_p$, i.e. $F_X(x) \le p$. Since $F_X^{-1+}(p)$ is the supremum of $A_p$, one is done. But I do not know how to conclude that from $P[X < x] \le p$.

$\Leftarrow$: I wanted to use that $F_X$ is non-decreasing:
$P[X < x] \le F_X(x) \le F_X(F_X^{-1+}(p)) \le p$, but I think this works only if $F_X^{-1+}(p) \in A_p$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your cdf right- or left-continuous?

Comment: Right-continuous, i.e. just a usual cdf.

Comment: Use the following obvious lemma: if $A$ is either $(-\infty,b)$ or $(-\infty,b]$, then $x\le b$ iff $(-\infty,x)\subset A$. @mlc has already shown how to use it in order to prove the necessity, and you can try to prove the sufficiency part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof uses the fact that $F(\cdot)$ is increasing and right-continuous.

(**EDIT**: the proof has been revised after zhoraster's comment.)

$(\Longrightarrow)\quad$

Suppose $P(X < x) \le p$. For any $z < x$, $P(X \le z) \le P(X < x)$ and thus 
$$P(X \le z) \le P(X < x) \le p$$
Thus, the set 
$$\{z \in \mathbb{R}: z < x\} \subseteq A_p$$
Taking the $\sup$ on both sides,
$$x = \sup \{z \in \mathbb{R}: z < x\} \le \sup A_p = F^{-1+}(p)$$

$(\Longleftarrow)\quad$ Suppose $x \le F^{-1+}(p)$. Then
$$\sup \{z \in \mathbb{R}: z < x\} = x \le F^{-1+}(p)$$
Take the limit from the left:
$$\lim_{z \uparrow x} F(z) \le \lim_{z \uparrow F^{-1+}(p)} F(z) $$
The LHS converges to $F(x^-)=P(X < x)$. As for the RHS, because $F_X^{-1+}(p) = \sup A_p$ and $A_p = \{z \in \mathbb R; F_X(z) \le p\}$, $F(z) \le p$; then the limit cannot be greater than $p$, and we obtain
$$P(X < z) \le\lim_{z \uparrow F^{-1+}(p)} F(z)\le p$$

Comment: I doubt the sufficiency (second) part.

Comment: @zhoraster May I ask please to point out which line is in doubt?

Comment: "The rhs converges to $p$" -- why is that?

Comment: @zhoraster Good catch! I have edited the proof.

Comment: Seems correct now.